# How can I make procmail check LDAP for mailing list?

Tags: ldap, openldap, procmail

I am new to LDAP. I have a procmail config that currently redirects mails to a set of recipients specified therein. I want to replace this hardcoded set of recipients (mail-ids) with a LDAP mailing list.

```
# Sample procmailrc config showing the redirection to recipients A, B and C.

:0
! recipientA@mydomain.com recipientB@mydomain.com recipientC@mydomain.com
```

I want to have these three recipients added to a LDAP mailing list and then want the procmail config to read from LDAP Server and send the mails to these recepients.

Comment: If you're going to create an LDAP mailing list, then why not just use the mailing list as the recipient?  Why do you want to email the members of the list individually?

Comment: Hi dg99, I am interested to use LDAP instead of the hardcoded recipient list because the list is very dynamic. I don't want to go and change the recipient list every time a user is added/removed. This is already taken care in LDAP. I want to leverage on this.

Comment: Right, so why not just send the email to the *list* address directly?  Then you don't have to download the recipients.  Just do `! list-name@mydomain.com`.